Why are particles assumed to be entangled even after a measurement in EPR thought experiment?
$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
The EPR paradox proposes that for two entangled particles AB sent in different directions, one can measure the position of particle A and calculate that of particle B. Then, B's momentum could be measured and that of A could be calculated from that. My question is, what would these calculations look like? Are they assumed to be done using quantum mechanics? To be precise, after the first position measurement, could we expect the two particle wave function to collapse to a tensor product of position eigenstates of A and B?
$$\Ket{\psi}_{pm}=\Ket{x_A}\otimes\Ket{x_B}$$
If so, that would mean that the entanglement was destroyed after the first measurement. Each particle could then be assumed to evolve through local unitaries (if there is no dissipation). If that is the case then the second measurement of B's momentum could not be expected to affect A/ predict A's momentum. But from the formulation of the thought experiment, it seems that it is insisted that the particles would stay entangled even after the first measurement. What am I missing? An answer with a mathematical treatment of the problem would be very helpful.

In general, the entanglement breaks down after a "measurement". The point of the EPR argument is, that this breaking down of entanglement happens instantaneously, and thus is a non-local process.

If I understand correctly, the measurement and subsequent collapse of an entangled state itself does not lead to a violation of locality because the wave function is not physical, and its collapse doesn't have to obey the laws of a physical process. It is the outcome of the collapse, the information about 'which' state was obtained, that has to follow locality. If that is the case then why do we insist that B would be in a state that it could only have 'known' to be in through some kind of superluminal effects? If locality is a premise of the argument, then this would not have been asserted.

1/2 I think this misses the actual point of EPR, for which entanglement is perhaps kind of besides the point (even though it's necessary for the set up of the "paradox"). EPR stresses that an experimenter has a choice of what basis to measure in, and so really the EPR paper is about counterfactuals. The idea is that we could have measured in a particular basis, and so there are "elements of reality" associated with those outcomes, even if the experiment is not performed (i.e., we chose to measure in a different basis)....

2/3 ...However, Bell and Kochen-Specker tells us that that's untenable. As Asher Peres said, "Unperformed experiments have no results." I'll say further that it feels like this question is really just about classical local correlations, which are perfectly fine: I can take a red card and a blue card and randomly put one in your wallet and one in mine. Then, I wait until you fly to Andromeda to open my wallet. I have a blue card, so instantly I "calculate" that you have a red. There's no QM here. Necessary for EPR is the existence of mutually exclusive bases in which I can choose to measure.

3/3 ...Finally, it's not necessary to think of the "collapse of the wave function" as some sort of physical process, other than the processes that are going on in our brain while we're thinking about the experiment.  There are plenty of information-based and subjective-probability interpretations of QM, in which the wave function is not a physical (ontic) object but rather an epistemic one, i.e., it represents the experimenter's information about the state of the system.

Thank you for the great explanation! I think I get it now. The idea of counterfactuals really helped. I think what confused me is that I've also seen a lot of discussions which invoke consecutive measurements. Are they are misinterpretation, or could the idea be conveyed using those too?

@march The kind of correlations the Bell inequality is consered with are not of the kind, as your example with the red and the blue card. This is the whole point of the theorem. It was already pointed out by Bell himself in his article BERTLMANN’S SOCKS AND THE NATURE OF
REALITY.

@LukasNullmeier I know! That's my point! - the way I read the post, the OP seems to think that these types of classical correlations are the point of EPR. But of course they can't be, because these types of correlations are classical, and of course quantum mechanically, there are types of correlations that violate Bell inequalities and the like. That's part of what I was trying to get at with my comments (along with trying to clarify what EPR is actually about, which is often gotten wrong).

@UVcatastrophe. Yes: I believe that descriptions of EPR that invoke consecutive measurements (whether they are consecutive measurements on the same system or one measurement on one system and one measurement on the other) are completely missing the point of EPR's argument. The results of consecutive measurements are an important aspect of QM measurement theory, sure, but that is not what EPR was trying to get at.  I found this write-up helpful.

@march Yes, I understand that quantum correlations don't follow local realism. I'm just trying to revert back to the original thought experiment and trying to pinpoint at what point their line of reasoning starts to go wrong (given what we know now). I understand that the premise of realism itself was flawed, but I'm trying to see at what point that becomes relevant in the argument. Is it that throughout the argument, they never invoke QM and only rely on classical mechanics for the proposed calculations of position and momenta? Is the wave function not even a part of this discussion?

@UVcatastrophe did you read the EPR paper? The initial state is superposition of anticorrelated states of the parts. First measurement changes the state in a known way,  and position / momentum of the other part is then predicted with certainty from this collapsed quantum state.

@JánLalinský I did read it a while ago, but thanks for clarifying that it uses quantum states. The crux on my original question then still remains. The collapsed state after the first measurement would be separable. Any subsequent measurement on B's momentum should not be expected to predict that of A, right?

Measurement does not predict, it collapses the quantum state, and then we can make predictions based on the new collapsed quantum state. This prediction can be done in any case, but it need not be in agreement with measurement result we get later. If position of A was measured at time $t_0$, then prediction of value of A's momentum at time $t>t_0$ will be almost always wrong. Making prediction (or retrodiction) about A's momentum at times $t<t_0$ can't be shown to be either correct or wrong, one can assign a lot to unmeasured past, without getting into trouble, but it is speculative.
